# Merging two data sets but without duplications

Tags: r, merge, tidyr

I would like to attach information from one dataframe and append it to another but I just can't get the merge to work the way I want it.

My example:

```
a <- data.frame(well = c(222, 222, 222, 21, 21,21,43,64,64,64),
                   area = c("H", "H", "H", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E"))
```

```
b <- data.frame(well = c(222, 21, 43, 64),
                   score = c(12000, 10000, 9000, 20000))
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
 well score area
1  222 12000 H
2   21 10000 C
3   43  9000 D
4   64 20000 E
```

But I get this (I don't want the well numbers to duplicate):

```
 well area score
1    21    C 10000
2    21    C 10000
3    21    C 10000
4    43    D  9000
5    64    E 20000
6    64    E 20000
7    64    E 20000
8   222    H 12000
9   222    H 12000
10  222    H 12000
```

My actual data contains many hundred rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(unique(a))[b, on = .(well)]
#   well area score
#1:  222    H 12000
#2:   21    C 10000
#3:   43    D  9000
#4:   64    E 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have duplicates in `a`, you are getting them in `merge` as well. One option is to have only `unique` rows of `a` and then `merge`

```
merge(unique(a), b)

#  well area score
#1   21    C 10000
#2   43    D  9000
#3   64    E 20000
#4  222    H 12000
```

Or take `unique` after merging

```
unique(merge(a, b))
```

---

which can be done using `dplyr` by `left_join` and `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(distinct(a), b)
left_join(a, b) %>% distinct()
```